# How do I add a logout feature in a WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to WordPress and developing a WP plugin that can make signin ,signout and signup. So far this plugin can login but I cannot make it logout. I have tried `unset($_SESSION['user_id']);` and `session_destroy();` functions but they didn't work.

Following is my code that can login, can any one help me make logout feature?

---

```
<?php
    /*this block of code is preventing user from submitting empty email or password*/
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $pass_hash = md5($password);

        if( !empty($email) && !empty($password) ){

            $query="SELECT `ID` FROM `vrm_users` WHERE `user_email`='$email' AND `user_pass`='$pass_hash'"; 
            if($query_run= mysql_query($query)){

                $query_num_rows= mysql_num_rows($query_run);
                if($query_num_rows==0){

                    echo'Invalid Login';

                }else if($query_num_rows==1) {

                    $user_id=mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'ID');
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    //header('Location: test_form.php');

                }//if($query_num_rows==0) ends here


            }//if($query_run= mysql_query($query)) ends here    
        }else{

            echo'Please Enter Email & Password';

        }//if( !empty($email) && !empty($password) ends here!


    }//if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) ends here





    /*
    Shortcode: [loginform]
    Description: Craetes A form that takes inputs
    */

    /*  Login Form  */
    function form_shortcode(){

        return  '<div class="loginform">
            <h2>Custom VRM LOGIN FORM</h2>
            <form action="" method="POST">

                <input type="email" name="email">Email<br>
                <input type="password" name="password">Password<br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"><br>

            </form>
            </div>';

    }//form_shortcode()


    add_shortcode('loginform', 'form_shortcode');




?>
```

Comment: Why can't you use the built in [wp_logout()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout) function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [wp_logout_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url) template tag to generate a logout link in your plugin file.

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url( '/redirect_page' ) ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

Comment: thanks a lot... one more thing i wanna ask u. is there any builtin wordpress function to create login form or any thing relating that?

Comment: I think you should try Google: https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=t4o7VK3rOfTH8getmIHICg&gws_rd=ssl#q=wordpress+login+form

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `wp_logout_url()`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url